# FFmpeg compilation with encoder x264 not found Windows

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, compilation, mingw, x264

FFmpeg compilation with encoder x264 not found Windows

I am trying to compile FFmpeg with several encoder (x264, NVENC). I already
managed to compile FFmpeg with MinGW and also x264 but I do not know how I can
tell where my compiled encoders are.

I have a folder where my FFmpeg sources are and in this directory I have my
compiled x264 encoder in a subfolder called x264.

OS: Windows 10

Compiler: MinGW

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to install x264 to the correct place. When building x264, use this
   or similar:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw
   ```

   [Example](//github.com/svnpenn/glade/blob/affe41f/x264/install.sh#L5-L6)
2. Use the appropriate options when compiling FFmpeg, for example:

   ```
   ./configure --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32-
   ```

   [Example](//github.com/svnpenn/glade/blob/affe41f/ffmpeg/install.sh#L5-L7)

This will allow FFmpeg to find your build tools and libraries.